# How can I set up a site-wide default setting opens any .pdf file in a new window?

Tags: css, links, squarespace

I'm currently using Squarespace to build my website. I'm looking to implement a function where any time a visitor encounters a hyperlink .pdf file, it automatically opens in a new window. While I understand I can manually set this up for each file individually, I would prefer to have a site-wide default configuration. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!